# Get a value from few drop down

Tags: javascript, onchange, dropdown

I want to get a value from few dropdown, this few dropdown have a same name in 
a table of database.
And  user can see only one dropdown base on their previous selection, but I can't detect which dropdown is selected by users.So I make something bellow:

```
        $dropvalue = "GetFromJavaascriptBellow" //use to get value from javascript bellow

    <select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1">
    <option selected disabled>-- Please select a option --</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="def">def</option>
    <option value="ghi">ghi</option>
    </select>

    <select id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2">
    <option selected disabled>-- Please select a option --</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="456">456</option>
    <option value="789">789</option>
    </select>

    <select id="dropdown3" name="dropdown3">
    <option selected disabled>-- Please select a option --</option>
    <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
    <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
    <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $('#dropdown1').change(function () {
             if ( this.value != '' || this.value != NULL)
          {
            $dropvalue = this.value //This line is what I can't do (is it possible php variable get value from javascript?)
          }
          else
          {

          }
        });

        $('#dropdown2').change(function () {
             if ( this.value != '' || this.value != NULL)
          {
            $dropvalue = this.value //This line is what I can't do (is it possible php variable get value from javascript?)
          }
          else
          {

          }
        });

        $('#dropdown3').change(function () {
             if ( this.value != '' || this.value != NULL)
          {
            $dropvalue = this.value //This line is what I can't do (is it possible php variable get value from javascript?)
          }
          else
          {

          }
        });
    </script>
```

My current solution is using ajax to get all of the value from all drop down, and set the default value ='0' to all dropdown, in ajax using if else statement to check which dropdown is not equal to 0 to confirm what is my value and which dropdown is.
But this way is conflict with my another function, so I finding another way to did it

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use `querySelectorAll`

```js
x=document.querySelectorAll("select.abc");
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].addEventListener("change",function(){
        console.log(this.value);  // your ajax call or whatever function you want excute
    });
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" class="abc">
  <option selected disabled>-- Please select a option --</option>
  <option value="abc">abc</option>
  <option value="def">def</option>
  <option value="ghi">ghi</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2" class="abc">
  <option selected disabled>-- Please select a option --</option>
  <option value="123">123</option>
  <option value="456">456</option>
  <option value="789">789</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown3" name="dropdown3">
  <option selected disabled>-- Please select a option --</option>
  <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
  <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
  <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: May I know how to get the value of console log in php? I'm not so sure about how to use console log

Comment: here console.log is just to show in javascript. you can get the value using `this.value`, (just replace console.log(this.value) to $dropvalue = this.value)

Comment: And actually you function is to detect all of the dropdown, but actually my page have another another dropdown no need to get their value when change. This may confuse me when getting all the value of dropdown when change

Comment: edited the code. Now it will select only those drop down who has class="abc" in it.

Comment: I'm very appreciate with you answer, but we can't use only `$dropvalue = this.value` this kind of simple code to get a value from javascript to php.

Comment: I knew maybe my question have no answer to solve,very sorry about it. I'm just looking for any possible way to do it.Because I'm new to php and still hope to learn it more...

Comment: Nevermind, at least you've try to help me to solve the problem. Btw , thank you for helping :)